# Get TextView string from recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview contain cardlayout with three textviews(name, email, phone) fetched from database. I want to hide the cardlayout from the recyclerview if it contains name equal to certain string. What i tried is after fetching data from database, i used if statement to compare name with string and if it's equal them make the cardlayout invisible. but many cardlayout are getting invisible if condition satisfy

```
 if (dealer.getName().equals("abcde"))
     cardlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I think the best approach to this problem would be to remove the corresponding item from the Item List.

Comment: yes, and please show your rv adapter class, and activity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your RecyclerView items are having multiple items with `visibility` of `Gone`.

And I'm sure you're doing that logic in `onBindViewHolder()` in `RecyclerView.Adapter`

**Why are you in such a situation?**

`onBindViewHolder()` is called with that item when the item is init , and when you scroll to another position you don't see that item anymore and scroll back to that item position.

In the RecyclerView.Adapter documentation, Google says about `onBindViewHolder()`:

> Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should update the contents of the RecyclerView.ViewHolder.itemView to reflect the item at the given position.

And

> you should only use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep a copy of it.

For this reason, When you re-scroll the item before it or after it, and you don't set an else case for your item, then the value of the item before it or after it in `onBindViewHolder` will get your content back on the item where you set the cardlayout hidden logic.

**How to solve the problem?**

For hidden logic that shows or modifies view items in `onBindViewHolder()`, make sure that if you have case `if` you have case `else`.

*YourRecyclerViewAdapter.kt*

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
    if (dealer.name == "abcde") {
        cardLayout.visibility = View.GONE
    } else { // You should have else case to return the correct content for other positions
        cardLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    ...
}
```